# activerecord enum and dirty attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have a model that defines an [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) like so :

`enum status: [ :init, :requested, :packed, :paid, :shipped ]`

I also have the following methods which uses dirty attributes.

```
  def shipment_requested
    status_changed?(from: :init, to: :requested)
  end

  def shipment_packed
    status_changed?(from: :requested, to: :packed)
  end

  def shipment_paid
    status_changed?(from: :packed, to: :paid)
  end

  def shipment_shipped
    status_changed?(from: :paid, to: :shipped)
  end
```

there are lots of model callbacks that relies on this ,like updating timestamps , and sending emails.

but unfortunately none of this works.

```
sh = Shipment.find(1)
sh.init?
=> true
sh.requested!
sh.requested?
=> true
sh.shipment_requested
=> false
```

**what's wrong with the above code ? is this a bug ?**

I could have set all the values manually at the controller but this defeats the purpose of using enum which comes with pretty nice features as per the docs above , like defining scopes and methods to check for `status`

Comment: What is `status_changed?` ?

Comment: [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) is exactly designed for such cases.

Comment: @Pavan [rails dirty attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: Try using `self.status_changed?(from: :init, to: :requested)`

Comment: @Pavan it didn't work. I think it is the `!` that saves the model without running validations but I am not sure I am looking into the docs. I might have to redefine the same methods again in the model to use the regular version without `update!`

Comment: @31piy I am trying to make it work without relying on an other gems,AASM seems too complicated for what I am trying to do but nonetheless , if I felt that I am hacking to make it work, I ll switch to that gem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to send values as strings to `changed?` method:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  enum type: [:single, :double, :triple]
end

e = Entry.first
e.type # => "single"
e.type = :double
# notice here values are strings, not symbols
e.type_change # => ["single", "double"]
e.type_changed?(from: :single, to: :double) # => false
e.type_changed?(from: "single", to: "double") # => true
```

Comment: Thanks ! is there a way to avoid hard coding string literals in inside the model dirty attribute methods ?

Comment: Well, how did I missed this? :) Nice one!

Comment: @static I only know how to remove string for a new value: `e.type_was == "single" && e.double?`